# How can i write linux gdb command?

Tags: linux, command-line, gdb

What is the **gdb command** that executes 3 lines but does not enter the function when it encounters a function?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure - but maybe you are looking for the 'until' command? If called with a location it will:

> Continue running your program until either the specified location is reached, or the current stack frame returns.

Also have a look at [Continuing and Stepping](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html) in the GDB manual. Alternatively you can just call 'next' with a number of executions. Also described in the link. So in your case

```
next 3
```

All commands will, however, execute the function calls that are in their path. They will just not 'step' into them.